# Nuget package manager failed for project, Unable to find version 5.2.6 of package ‘Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I try to set up an application but I am facing the below error:

> Nuget package restore failed for *project ProjectName: Unable to find version ‘5.2.6’ of package ‘Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc’. C:/Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NugetPackages: Package ‘Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.6’ is not found on source ‘c:\Program files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NugetPackages\’. http://ncrsdk-lib.ncrcorp********* : Package ‘Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.6’ is not found on source ‘http://ncrsdk-lib.ncrcorp.net/********’*

I tried to run the following command in the package manager console:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.6
```

I got the error some packages are missing from the solution. The package needs to be restored In order to build the dependency graph.

I clicked on the restore packages button and that gives a message unable to restore.

Comment: That's a very odd domain as a source of NuGet packages. Have you set a different NuGet source in Tools | Options | NuGet Package Manager | Package Sources?

Comment: Hi Richard, yes I have added the package  source as the link which I have shared above

Answer (score 1):

I cleared the package cache and added nuget.org to the package sources(was missing before) , This fixed the issue.

Source - [An error occurred while trying to restore packages. Please try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153474/an-error-occurred-while-trying-to-restore-packages-please-try-again)

Answer (score 0):

The package does not exist in the mentioned source , try to point your source to official nuget.org website , you have to options in order to force it to point to the correct one

Command Line

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.6 -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Or from Visual Studio you can select the correct source or configure a new source to point the official nuget.org
[image]

Comment: I Tried running the above command line from the package manager console, also tried changing to Source packages to All and 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline packages' still i see the error 'Install-Package : Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution. The packages need to be restored in order to build the dependency graph. Restore the packages before'

Comment: clearing the package cache and adding nuget.org to the package sources fixed the problem.

Comment: Great ! You can mark this answer as a solution as it's mention that you need to add nuget.org to the sources (red circle) otherwise you can improve it so it can help someone else

Answer (score 0):

From the error message looks like you are looking for a version that no longer exists and cannot tell which Package source you have selected.
Its trying to download the package form "http://ncrsdk-lib.ncrcorp********" where as the package may be removed from there. Try installing the the same package from source nuget.org only.